# Using typings to install es6-shim

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

### I am running the angularjs2/TypeScript project on vs 2015

and follow the document on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-4.html

While facing the Step 3.Use PackageInstaller to install typings for es6-shim.

I use the typings to install es6-shim, but it throw out the error that

> typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/es6-shim/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

This is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Seems to be a bug. You can [download the definition here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/es6-shim) (file `es6-shim.d.ts`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has changed in Typings 1.0.0.  Ambient types have been renamed to Global types.  Additionally, global types will no longer be installed from Definitely Typed by default.  More information in the [release notes](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

You can install a global type from the Definitely Typed repository with

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```